# SQL proxy for SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I can't find what I need or I don't know what to search.

Because we are a large team with different setup in our locals, if is possible somehow to enforce connection strings to be persistent across our locals.

Example: In config files

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SomeEntities" 
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=tests;...rest of it..."/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

As in my case, because I installed SQL DEVELOPER (version is irrelevant) my local connection will be ***"data source=.\;initial catalog=tests;...rest of it..."***

Is it possible to set a Proxy in SQL Server Configuration Manager for
< SQLSERVERNAME >\SQLEXPRESS to point on my local < SQLSERVERNAME >\

> I'm not looking to install SQL express, I want to setup a PROXY that
>   will help the team to use SQLEXPRESS connection string to work on any
>   installed SQL versions.